# Flutter Firebase Authentication, Routing and Widget Tree

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-layout

I am new to Flutter and have a question of the widget tree structure when implementing FireBase authentication.

Following is my widget tree at the moment.

[image]

In that I have use a Provider to access the FirebaseAuthentication object in clind widget and a StreamBuilder to identify Authentication State changes.

My question is where to put the Routing. I am not sure having two MaterialApps is the correct way. Putting routing inside HomePage class  doesn;t feel right and it also reload the application multiple times

part of the code is as below.

```
class LandingPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const LandingPage();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final firebaseAuth = Provider.of<FirebaseAuth>(context);
  final SecureStorage secureStorage = SecureStorage();
  void checkAndLoginWithSavedCredentials() {
    if (kIsWeb) {
    } else if (Platform.isAndroid || Platform.isIOS) {
      print(secureStorage.readSecureData('email'));
    }
}
return StreamBuilder<User>(
    stream: firebaseAuth.authStateChanges(),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<User> snapshot) {
      checkAndLoginWithSavedCredentials();
      print(snapshot.connectionState.toString());
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
        //final bool signedIn = snapshot.hasData;
        User user = snapshot.data;
        return user == null ? LoginScreen() : HomeScreen();
        //return signedIn ? DashBoard() : FirstView();
      } else {
        return LoginScreen();
      }
    });
 }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  initialRoute: '/home',
  routes: {
    '/': (context) => LandingPage(),
    '/home': (context) => HomeScreen(),
    '/notifications': (context) => NotificationList(),
    '/fitness': (context) => FitnessScreen(),
    '/settings': (context) => SettingsScreen(),
  },
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
 );
 }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
After the suggestions I changed my code as below.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Provider<FirebaseAuth>(
  create: (context) => FirebaseAuth.instance,
  child: MaterialApp(
    initialRoute: '/',
    routes: {
      '/': (context) => LandingPage(),
      '/home': (context) => HomeScreen(),
      '/notifications': (context) => NotificationList(),
      '/fitness': (context) => FitnessScreen(),
      '/settings': (context) => SettingsScreen(),
    },
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
   ), 
  );
 }
}

class LandingPage extends StatelessWidget {
const LandingPage();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final firebaseAuth = Provider.of<FirebaseAuth>(context);
}

return StreamBuilder<User>(
    stream: firebaseAuth.authStateChanges(),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<User> snapshot) {
      print(snapshot.connectionState.toString());
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
        User user = snapshot.data;
        print(user == null);
        if (user == null) {
          print('loading Login Screen ...');
          return LoginScreen();
        } else {
          print('loading Home Screen ...');
          return HomeScreen();
        }
      } else {
        return LoginScreen();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Now the app doesn't reload multiple time but when the SignOut occurs down the widget tree, it does not change the route. The LandingPage does return the LoginPage widget but no route transition happen and app states with the same widget where SignOut happened.

[image]

I can do a forced route transition within the streamBuilder but that is not the way to implement it I assume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve it by moving the Sign Out option into the HomeScreen itself. When the Signout happens down the widget tree, it doesn't do the routing. Even though the LandingPage widget return a LoginPage at that point, there is no routing change to run the Build method of LandingPage class.

So my solution was

- Remove /home and /login (as suggested) routes and let the authStateChanges() to govern which widget is returned by the LandingPage class.
- Move the SignOut option to HomeScreen iteself

Alternative solution is to do the Navigator.pop() once the signout button is pressed. But this splashes the HomeScreen for a sub-second before rendering the LoginScreen. Hence I didn't like it. Not sure whether there is a better way to do it if your SignOut call is down the widget tree.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the entire app under `MaterialApp`, your other screen such as `LandingPage`, `Home` etc. doesn't have to be a MaterialApp, instead they can just be a `Scaffold`.

Comment: Thanks. But then by routing will happen at the top level where I need the HomePage to be accessible only with a state change

Comment: Home page will still be accessible only after state change. Your routing logic will make sure of that.

Answer (score 0):

Routes should be defined in My app() in `main.dart`

In MyApp() use `Stream builder(..` in `home:`
Like this:

> Please note you should replace Login page and others with named routes like '/login'

```
home: StreamBuilder<User>(
    stream: firebaseAuth.authStateChanges(),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<User> snapshot) {
      checkAndLoginWithSavedCredentials();
      print(snapshot.connectionState.toString());
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
        //final bool signedIn = snapshot.hasData;
        User user = snapshot.data;
        return user == null ? LoginScreen() : HomeScreen();
        //return signedIn ? DashBoard() : FirstView();
      } else {
        return LoginScreen();
      }
    })
```

Comment: Thanks you. If we are using routing in the MyApp() home: should not be used I guess, isn't it?  Are you refereing to an intermediate class to handle the StreamBuilder in that case which will load as the intialRoute?

Comment: Would you mind giving me a sample MyApp() class. I might have got it wrong.